# After ajax success show child table in if condition in ajax success

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
This is an HTML table with all buttons
```

On click of a button in table row button, status has to be updated in backend PHP and in ajax success I have to display child table

```
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Drawing</th>
      <th style="display:none">Overview</th>
      <th>Stage</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1">
      <td><button  type="button" class="button clarify" >Clarify</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button allot">Allott</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button start">Started/Pused</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button correctit">Quality Checking</button><td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button send">Send</button></td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="2">
      <td><button  type="button" class="button clarify" >Clarify</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button allot">Allott</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button start">Started/Pused</button></td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button correctit">Quality Checking</button><td>
      <td><button type="button"  class="button send">Send</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

here is the ajax call each click on the button status has to update and if the button status or data is == 2 then I want to display the child table

```
 
$(".button").click(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  //alert("am button");
  var drawingid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
  var stage_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.button').val();
  // alert(stage_id);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "stage2.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      "drawingID": drawingid,
      "stage_ID": stage_id

    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      if ( data == 2) {
      **//here if the data is == 2 then show child table with dropdown** $this.parent().parent().find('.button').val(data);
$this.parent().parent().find('.button').html('Allott').addClass('allot').removeClass('clarify');
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
        table = $('#' + id).DataTable();
        var row = table.row(tr);

        // Open this row
        row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pass 0/1 an additinal value in ajax, and run statement/function by using an "if"

Comment: No i want to display child table if data is 2 in if condition

Comment: **see where you are executing function Exampl on  : stage2.php**

e.g. 
`if (insert query successful on page stage2.php) {echo "2"}  else { echo "0" };`

aap 2 ke alawa kucch bhi print nahi karegi warna output nahi ayega
data's meaning is out put of ajax calling page
then 
` if ($variable == 2 ){  // statement }`

Comment: show me code of stage2.php, so may I can tell the method

Comment: see do not , am repeating do not use ajax directly  > send values to stage2.php manually like we send values using form >>> see what output it is producing on stage2.php on success and failure >>> make echo / output accordingly >> on successful execution it has to produce only "2", other wise it wont work

Comment: Ok how can i send stage2.php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235325/discussion-between-thejashwini-l-and-shubham-dange).

Comment: anyone plz help me out in this